# dotnet core, copy dependencies to output directory on build

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-assembly, build-dependencies

I'm currently working on a .net (dotnet) core console application (app) which should load plugins from a `/plugins/` folder.

The plugins reference an internal project called `Data` which provides the context implementation for the entity framework v2.0.1. This project is references using a nuget package.

When I run my application I get the following debug output (reflection exception)

> - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore,
>     Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>     The system cannot find the file specified.

I found a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll` file in this path `C:\Users\Tobias\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore\2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll` which I copied into the plugins folder.

After I copied the file the exception disappeared but a lot of other dependency errors occurred:

> - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.3000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263'.
>     The system cannot find the file specified.
> - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.3000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263'.
>     The system cannot find the file specified.
> - Could not load file or assembly 'Remotion.Linq, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fee00910d6e5f53b'. The system cannot
>     find the file specified.
> - Could not load file or assembly 'Remotion.Linq, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fee00910d6e5f53b'. The system cannot
>     find the file specified.
> - Could not load file or assembly 'Remotion.Linq, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fee00910d6e5f53b'. The system cannot
>     find the file specified.
> - ... (about ~90 more)

I don't want to copy all those references manually, and I don't think that I should have to.

Isn't there a way to copy all the dependencies on building in visual studio? Or maybe using cmd and `dotnet` command?

I couldn't find any help so far

Comment: you could use something like this in your csproj `<ItemGroup><None Update="/path/to/fileNamehere.extention" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" /></ItemGroup>` Which will copy a given file to the output directory on build.

Comment: @JamieTaylor this doesn't help since the files missing aren't ones I've implemented myself. They are nuget package references

Comment: In that case, I believe that the nuget packages should resolve and their contents be placed in the build output directory (as would any other nuget package). I wonder what's causing them to not be copied to the build output directory. I don't suppose you could share a redacted csproj?